# React native android app didn't start

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I have an android app use react native. The app run smoothly before. But for now it didn't run when I type command `react-native run-android`. I got error message like this:

> Error type 3
>
> Error: Activity class {com.test/com.test.MainActivity} does not exist.

And after that error, I can't run any new app. I run command `react-native init app_name`, `cd app_name`, and `react-native run-android`. The error message I got is:

> The development server returned response error code:500

Anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks ^^

Comment: check your android folder, is `MainActivity` really exist or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

Just type this command

```
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```